# angularjs: how to invoke controller based on his parent results

Tags: angularjs

I'm moving my very first steps with angularjs.

I have a controller which does a call to a service, which returns a list of urls (parent).

I would like to render a html *ul* for which each *li* is rendered by another controller (children) with its own template. I imagine something like this:

```
<ul ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="element in elements">
        <div ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
            {{oneField}} - {{anotherField}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first controller is easy to implement:

```
myApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('services/elements')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.elements = data;
    });
});
```

But for the second I have a problem, since I can't figure out how the controller could know which url use for the ajax call (DYNAMYC_URL):

```
myApp.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get(DYNAMYC_URL)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.element = data;
    });
});
```

Could you please suggest me which is the best way in angular to approach this problem?

I've also considered to do many calls inside the first controller, but it doesn't seem a clean solution to me.

Comment: From which variable the DYNAMYC_URL will come? Namely who provides this?

Comment: The first call (services/elements) returns a list of URL, each one of them should become DYNAMIC_URL.

Answer (score 0):

We will try to maintain the state of childRenderUrl function call in element while
initializing the element itself in ng-unit attribute.

Instead of DetailCtrl 
We write a function renderChild defined as

```
 $scope.renderChild =function(element)
 { 
    $http.get(element.url)
     .success(function(data) {
     // add all required fields to element here 
      element.otherField=data.otherField;
      element.sometherField=data.sometherField;
      //a $scope.$digest may be required here
   });
 }
```

Your display logic would be

```
       <ul ng-controller="ListCtrl">
         <li ng-repeat="element in elements">
          <div ng-init="renderChild(element)">
            {{element.oneField}} - {{element.anotherField}}
           </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
```

On initializing we would call the renderChild method which would 
add two properties to the element object that would be aptly displayed by 
expressions  {{element.oneField}} - {{element.anotherField}}

Comment: I've just tried your approach but there should be something wrong: the same element is rendered two times, instead of rendering two different elements; what do you mean with $scope.$digest?

Comment: The same element is not rendered twice. Its just that for child element we are adding additional parameters before initializing. can you tell me what error you are getting using this approach ? and $scope.$digest is required some times to update the binding between models and dom.

Comment: In my case the list contains two URLs. With your approach the renderChild is called two times (correctly) but it seems that element.oneField and element.anotherField has always the same values, which is the one retrieved from the first URL.

Comment: Can you add an extra parameter to element eg.
element.childElement
and then add properties to this childElement.
so the logic would luk like 
 element.childElement={};
 element.childElement.otherField=data.otherField;
 element.childElement.sometherField=data.sometherField;

And then display using 
{{element.childElement.oneField}} - {{element.childElement.anotherField}}

Comment: I'm sorry but the result is as in the previous comment.